# Matrix of random permutations

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, random, permutation

I want to create a matrix of x columns of random permutations from 1 to 10, say. The command randperm(10) works great, yet I would like to create x of those.

Is there a way to do it without a loop?
Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that each permutation should be generated with the same probability and independently of others (and so some permutations can happen to be the same).

To generate `x` permutations in a **vectorized** way you can use:

```
N = 10; % population
x = 5; % desired number of permutations
[~, result] = sort(rand(x,N), 2);
```

This gives (example):

```
result =
     7     1     2     9     6    10     3     4     5     8
     2     6     4    10     1     7     5     9     3     8
     6    10     2     7     9     5     4     3     1     8
     7     5     4     6     2    10     8     1     3     9
     6     4     2     8    10     9     5     1     7     3
```

#### How this works

A simple way to generate *one* permutation of `1`, ..., `N` is

- Generate `N` random numbers.
- Sort them, and get the *indices* of the sorting. Those indices are a random permutation of the integers `1`, ..., `N`.

So, to generate `x` permutations in a vectorized way:

- Generate an `x`-by-`N` matrix of random numbers.
- Sort each row, and get the indices of each sorting.

Comment: Amazing approach!  Btw you can avoid the transpose with just this: `[~,result]=sort(rand(x,N),2)`

Comment: @SardarUsama Good idea! Edited

Comment: This is the method I have always used.  Thanks for sharing. +1.

Comment: @rayryeng Yes, I remember having talked about this approach in the past, maybe we discussed about it :-)

Answer (score 2):

If what you're after is a one-liner, I suppose you could use arrayfun

```
x = 10;
cell2mat (arrayfun (@(n) randperm (10).', [1:x], 'UniformOutput', false))
```

Note that this does not guarantee unique permutations however, nor is it necessarily faster than a for loop.

Comment: Didn't you mean to write `cell2mat (arrayfun (@(` **`y`** `)`... ?  (or any other variable) (Your code will work in Octave though)

Comment: @SardarUsama oh, does that not work in matlab?? Thanks, I'll correct that!

Comment: Not sure about the latest version/s but not till 2016a

Answer (score 1):

### Without for loop

The below code works but is not spatially optimal because all `n!` permutations before sampling from them.

**O(perms) time constraint**

**O(n!) space constraint**

```
mat = datasample(perms(1:n),k,'Replace',false);
```

---

### With for loop

If you use a loop you could do something like the following. The downside here is that you'll have to check your output matrix every loop (if you need to ensure unique permutations).

**O(n!) time constraints**

**O(k) space constraints**

```
mat = zeros(x,n)
count = 1;
while count < x+1
   temp = randperm(n);

   if ismember(temp,mat,'rows')
       mat(count,:) = temp;
       count = count + 1;
   end
end
```

---

### Summary

If you have a large `n` you'll run into issues with `n!` space constraints before `n!`time in MATLAB so I'd recommend the **second solution.**

If you have large `k/n!` the **first solution** will be significantly faster and similar space constraints

If you have low `k and n` the first solution ensures you do not need to check for unique permutations so I'd go with that for that reason.

Comment: Ok so I am using a loop. Say my parameters are n=3,r=2. I get a permutation like

Comment: Caveat: [**`datasample`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/datasample.html) requires *Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox*